# How save PySpark dataframe to parquet file

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I just installed PySpark because I don't need Hadoop it doesn't recommended in the PySpark documenation. Do all people install Hadoop for just save a parquet in local machine ?

My code :

```
from datetime import datetime, date
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import Row, SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Example").getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([
      Row(a=1, b=2., c='string1', d=date(2000, 1, 1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0)),
      Row(a=2, b=3., c='string2', d=date(2000, 2, 1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 2, 12, 0)),
      Row(a=4, b=5., c='string3', d=date(2000, 3, 1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 3, 12, 0))
])
df.write.parquet('bar.parquet') # error
```

My OS:

- Windows 11
- Python 3.11.8
- PySpark 3.5.0
- Notebook VS Code

My error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 12
      5 spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Example").getOrCreate()
      6 df = spark.createDataFrame([
      7     Row(a=1, b=2., c='string1', d=date(2000, 1, 1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0)),
      8     Row(a=2, b=3., c='string2', d=date(2000, 2, 1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 2, 12, 0)),
      9     Row(a=4, b=5., c='string3', d=date(2000, 3, 1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 3, 12, 0))
     10 ])
---> 12 df.write.parquet('bar.parquet')

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py:1721, in DataFrameWriter.parquet(self, path, mode, partitionBy, compression)
   1719     self.partitionBy(partitionBy)
   1720 self._set_opts(compression=compression)
-> 1721 self._jwrite.parquet(path)

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1317     self.command_header +\
   1318     args_command +\
   1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
   1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py:179, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    177 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    178     try:
--> 179         return f(*a, **kw)
    180     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    181         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o43.parquet.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset. -see https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems
```

Comment: Just in case: check `type(df)` other idea: do you have write permissions to the directory in which you are running this code? Try i.e `/tmp/bar.parquet` if on Linux

Comment: your code works on Linux. Trying to save `/bar.parquet` (no write permission) gives a different error. I guess the last line of your error points to some issues with configuration of spark on Windows.

Comment: Yes, I'm admin `type(df)` is `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame`. I can just try on Windows 11.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need Hadoop to save parquet files.

One way is to use `pandas` dataframe and directly write:

```
df.to_parquet('bar.parquet')
```

Another is to use `PyArrow`

Check these answers for detail description :

**[Parquet without Hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29279865/parquet-without-hadoop)**

**[How to view Apache Parquet file in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50933429/how-to-view-apache-parquet-file-in-windows)**

Comment: I tried it but `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_parquet'
`. I prefer to save it directly when `df `is Pyspark dataframe. I don't need Hadoop but why I have this error. I can't convert `df` to pyarrow parquet.

Comment: You need to convert it to pandas dataframe and then convert directly with pandas dataframe `df.to_parquet('bar.parquet')`

Comment: I know this method but my question is for how can I resolve it directly without pandas. My code works in Google Colab. Now I just would like to resolve it on my local machine.